# javascript dropdown redirect passing var issue

Tags: javascript

I have the follwoing code. a user adds a campaign_name and then chooses a segement name from the dropdown then it redirects back with a query string.

```
<option value="{{Request::url().'/'. $uploaded_segment->id .'/'}}"></option>




<script>
$(function() {
    // bind change event to select
    var campaign_name = $("#campaign_name").val();
    console.log(campaign_name);
    $('#uploaded_segment_id').on('change', function() {
        var url = $(this).val() + campaign_name; // get selected value
        console.log(url);
        if (url) { // require a URL
            window.location = url; // redirect
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

expected result: manage/campaigns/create/1/campaign_name
actual result: manage/campaigns/create/1/

I do not get an error, sometimes campaign_name is concatenated in the query string  and sometimes it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're grabbing the value of `#campaign_name` **immediately** when the page is shown. You want to do that in response to the `change` eevnt, presumably:

```
$(function() {
    // bind change event to select
    $('#uploaded_segment_id').on('change', function() {
        var campaign_name = $("#campaign_name").val(); // <=== *** MOVED ***
        console.log(campaign_name);
        var url = $(this).val() + campaign_name; // get selected value
        console.log(url);
        if (url) { // require a URL
            window.location = url; // redirect
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```